# Repeated division in Python produces incorrect results

Tags: python, math

I am calculating the division of an amount of money among several people. After the first person's payout is calculated, the other two are done incorrectly.

1/2 to Stan.
2/3 of what remains to Kyle.
The rest is to be split equally to Butters and Wendy.

My first split to Stan is correct but after that can't seem to figure out the correct way to code it.

```
def main():
    estate = int(input('Enter value of Kennys estate '))
    stan = estate / 2
    kyle = stan * .66
    wendy_butters = kyle / 2


    print('stan gets$ ',format (stan,' .2f'))
    print('kyle gets$ ',format (kyle,' .2f'))
    print('Butters and Wendy each get $ ',format (wendy_butters,' .2f'))

main ()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math problem, not a programming one.

Comment: Feel like Cartman is unfairly missing out here.

Comment: You seem to already try to optimize some math; just go by the classic ```rest=estate-stan```, ```rest=estate-stan-kyle``` approach. Take a pen and paper. (poor Cartman)

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    estate = int(input('Enter value of Kennys estate '))
    stan = estate / (2.0)
    kyle = (estate - stan) * (2.0/3)
    wendy_butters = (estate - (stan + kyle))/2.0


    print('stan gets$ ',format (stan,' .2f'))
    print('kyle gets$ ',format (kyle,' .2f'))
    print('Butters and Wendy each get $ ',format (wendy_butters,' .2f'))

main ()
```

I made changes in calculation, check if it works for you.

**output:**

```
Enter value of Kennys estate 450
stan gets$   225.00
kyle gets$   150.00
Butters and Wendy each get $   37.50
```

Comment: the output i am going for is Enter value of Kenny's estate 450
Stan gets $225.00
Kyle gets $150.00
Butters and Wendy each get $37.50

Comment: Made some changes and also output with 450

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you have is correct, but one note is doing `stan * .66` to calculate Kyle's portion is not exact, and it gets more inexact as `estate` gets larger.  You should be using Python 3 or `from __future__ import division`, then you can do

```
kyle = stan * 2 / 3
```

For calculating the last amount, after Stan and Kyle have their shares, the remaining balance is `estate - stan - kyle` -> `stan * 2 - stan - kyle` -> `stan - kyle`.  Simple math.

```
wendy_butters = (stan - kyle) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because of default integer division, you need to convert it to float division

`31/2 = 15` should have been `15.5`
So for Kyle, it is calculating as`15*.66`, rather than `16*.66` (the remaining one)

Solution:
For float division, You can either write it as
`31/2.0 = 15.5` or `31/(float(2)) = 15.5`